# UIImagePickerController and keypress

Tags: iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

I have created a simple subclass of the UIImagePickerController as follows:

```
@interface CustomImagePicker : UIImagePickerController <UITextViewDelegate> {
}

-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    // make sure to call the same method on the super class!!!
    //
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UITextView *textView = [[[UITextView alloc] init] autorelease];
    [self.view addSubview:textView];

    [textView becomeFirstResponder];
    [textView setDelegate:self];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(keyPressed:) name: UITextViewTextDidChangeNotification object: nil];

}

- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView{
    NSLog(@"Picture Taken 2");

    [self takePicture];
}

-(void) keyPressed: (NSNotification*) notification
{
    NSLog(@"Picture Taken 1");
    [self takePicture];
}
```

In my main window I open this up modally:

```
   camera = [[CustomImagePicker alloc] init]; 
            camera.delegate = self; 
            camera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera; 
            camera.allowsEditing = NO; 
            camera.showsCameraControls = NO;
            camera.wantsFullScreenLayout = NO;
            //camera.cameraOverlayView  = myView;

            [self presentModalViewController:camera animated:YES];
```

Neither the keypress or textviewDidChange ever get's called.

Anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not allowed to subclass the UIImagePickerController.

The documentation at -- 
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html
specifies
"*Important: The UIImagePickerController class supports portrait mode only. This class is intended to be used as-is and does not support subclassing.* "

Answer (score 0):

i believe it should work. Need some detailed information.

For an alternative way, try to use `UITextViewDelegate`

```
UITextView *textView = [[[UITextView alloc] init] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:textView];

[textView becomeFirstResponder];
[textView setDelegate:self];
```

And implement; `- (void)textViewDidChange:(UITextView *)textView;` method to your class.

For Reference : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UITextViewDelegate.html

Comment: Great idea, spot on, but in my code it is not working.  I have updated my query with the actual code, am I missing anything?

Comment: try to use -viewDidAppear instead of -viewWillAppear.

Comment: No change.  Thought it might have had a chance to initialize.

Comment: are you sure that your  `-(void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated` and `-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` methods are working correctly. Try to add breakpoint in those methods and see if debugger stops on those breakpoints. If they are not working at all then your presentation of modal view controller has problem. Try to present from some other viewController exits in the window at first index. I know it is weird but apple has some bug in there.